# Why does my C program give error : warning: implicit declaration of function ‘palindrome’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Tags: c, compiler-errors, c-strings, palindrome, function-declaration

Aim : To check if a string is Palindrome or not

Error :
at Line 32 warning: implicit declaration of function ‘palindrome’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Code :

```
int palindrome(char[] A)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; A[i] != '\0'; i++) { } i = i-1; // Keeping the index pointer at final element rather than null pointer.
    
    int j;
    
    for(j=0; j<i ; i--, j++)
    {
        if(A[i] != A[j])
            return 0;
        
    }
    
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    char A[] = "madam";
    
    if(palindrome(A)) // Line of Error 
        printf("Yes, Palindrome");
    else
        printf("No!");
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you GCC or clang, which i think is the case based on the flags and output, it will already compile at `int palindrome(char[] A)`, even without any warning flags (which you should enable anyway). Always start at the top of the error/warning list, there is a chance that fixing them will solve the following errors/warnings too.

Comment: There is the standard C function `strlen()` which even most freestanding should have. No need to create your own loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This declaration of the function

```
int palindrome(char[] A)
```

is incorrect. It seems you mean

```
int palindrome(char A[])
```

Moreover the function should be declared like

```
int palindrome( const char A[])
```

because the passed string is not changed within the function.

And do not use all uppercase letters in names of identifiers. I would declare the function like

```
int palindrome( const char *s )
```

This for loop

```
for(i = 0; A[i] != '\n'; i++) { }
```

can invoke undefined behavior if the passed string does not contain the new line character '`\n'`.

Again it seems you mean

```
for(i = 0; A[i] != '\0'; i++) { }
```

It would be better to substitute this loop for a while loop as for example

```
int i = 0;
while ( A[i] != '\0' ) i++;
```

Also instead of the type `int` used tp determine the length of a string you should use the type `size_t` because in general the type `int` can be not large enough to store possible lengths of strings.

Without using standard C string functions the function can be defined as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int palindrome( const char *s )
{
    size_t first = 0;
    size_t last  = 0;
    
    while ( s[last] ) ++last;
    
    if ( first != last )
    {
        while ( first < --last && s[first] == s[last] ) ++first;
    }

    return !( first < last );
}

int main( void ) 
{
    const char *s = "A";
    
    printf( "\"%s\" is a palindrome - %s\n", s, palindrome( s ) ? "true" : "false" );
    
    s = "AA";
    
    printf( "\"%s\" is a palindrome - %s\n", s, palindrome( s ) ? "true" : "false" );
    
    s = "AB";
    
    printf( "\"%s\" is a palindrome - %s\n", s, palindrome( s ) ? "true" : "false" );
    
    s = "ABA";
    
    printf( "\"%s\" is a palindrome - %s\n", s, palindrome( s ) ? "true" : "false" );
    
    s = "ABBA";
    
    printf( "\"%s\" is a palindrome - %s\n", s, palindrome( s ) ? "true" : "false" );
    
    s = "ABCA";
    
    printf( "\"%s\" is a palindrome - %s\n", s, palindrome( s ) ? "true" : "false" );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"A" is a palindrome - true
"AA" is a palindrome - true
"AB" is a palindrome - false
"ABA" is a palindrome - true
"ABBA" is a palindrome - true
"ABCA" is a palindrome - false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
modify the method parameter declaration i.e. char A[] not char[] A

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int palindrome(char A[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; A[i] != '\0'; i++) { } i = i-1; // Keeping the index pointer at final element rather than null pointer.
    int j;
    
    for(j=0; j<i ; i--, j++)
    {
        if(A[i] != A[j])
            return 0;
        
    }
    
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    char A[] = "madam";
    
    if(palindrome(A)) // Line of Error 
        printf("Yes, Palindrome");
    else
        printf("No!");
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to add why this solved the problem. Code-only answers without any explanation are discouraged at SO.

Comment: Below line is creating issue.
int palindrome(char[] A)
{
}
We have to write like below and declaring & initialization of Array in C will be char A[] 
not like char[] A. 
int palindrome(char A[])
{}